# First time on BASH

Tags: bash, shell

This is my first time using bash in college and it's being pretty hard now.
The exercise is:

> Make a shell script which receives by parameter one word and a file list and adds the word in the beggining and ending of each file

So far what I've done is this:

```
#!bin/bash

word=$1;

i=2;
j=2;

for [ i -le $# ] in ls 
do
    for [ j -le $# ] in ls 
    do
        if [ $i = $j ] then
            $j=`word+$j+word`;
        fi
    done
done
```

and of course it doesn't work, but I really don't know why. 
If anybody could help, it'd be great.
Sorry by any language mistake or convention in SO, I just arrived here. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your script needs to take at least *2* arguments, the word and one or more file names. Then you actually need to modify the named files, adding the given word to the beginning and end of the files. You are just attempting to add the word to the beginning and end of another *string*.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an exercise I'll give the answer in the way I would have wanted to **learn** about it:

- Your script needs to take an arbitrary number of [arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments) - for example `./my_script.sh "my word" *.txt` (note the [space and quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) in the first parameter). There is a shell builtin command called `shift` which will *remove* the first argument from the argument list. The argument list is commonly referred to using `"$@"`, but there is a handy shortcut syntax in Bash to loop over all arguments which avoids it entirely:

  ```
  for argument
  do
      something with "$argument"
  done
  ```
- The exercise as originally stated says to add the string to the start and end of each *file*, not *filename*. There are plenty of examples of how to do that on this site and [unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).
- You'll want to be careful about the difference between [`[` (aka. `test`) and `[[`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29).
- Bash is not C - the `;` command terminator is implicit at end of line (except of course in multi-line strings, [here documents](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) and the like).